# Batch program to move shortcut file

Tags: windows, batch

I'm writing a short batch program to move a few shortcuts.

The problem is that Windows returns, "Can not find the file specified".

I imagine this is because either it's considered a system file (think user account controls petty level "system") or that it's hidden even though you don't have to `dir /a` to display it in a directory listing.

What do I need to change here? The file names/paths are all correct as I've directly copied them from Windows Explorer.

```
cd C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\System
mkdir Settings
cd C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu
dir
move "Default Programs.lnk" "C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\System\Settings"
pause
```

Comment: In your "CD" commands, the paths should be quoted because they contain spaces.

Comment: "Default Programs" sounds like a directory, not a link. In the **move** command, press the **Tab** key after typing `move Default` and see what the file name expands to. Likewise, use the **Tab** key to build up the target directory, to make sure that the path is correctly spelled and quoted, and to make sure that all the path components are accessible. (As the world's worst typist, I make frequent use of **Tab**.)

Comment: Looks like you have a copy & paste error: the `move` command is missing the `Programs` directory level between `Start Menu` and `System`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Solution

The problem lies in the following line of code:

```
move "Default Programs.lnk" "C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\System\Settings"
```

As pointed out by @Scott, the destination path is wrong. In particular:

```
Start Menu\System
```

That part should read:

```
Start Menu\Programs\System
```

### Remarks

Even if you were able to solve the problem, there are other things worth mentioning.

#### Change the current folder

```
cd C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\System
```

The above commands wouldn't work as you probably expect in case you are on a drive which isn't `C:`:

```
D:\>cd C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\System

D:\>mkdir Settings
```

In the example above, the `Settings` folder would be created in the root of the `D:` drive. To avoid this, use the `/d` parameter:

```
cd /d C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\System
```

The `cd` command doesn't treat spaces a delimiters when command extensions are enabled (by default, they are). It's a good idea to use quotes anyway:

```
cd /d "C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\System"
```

The folder might not be stored on the `C:` drive at all, though. Rather then hard-coding the full path, you can use the `%ProgramData%` [environment variable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Environment_variable#Microsoft_Windows) which was introduced with Windows Vista:

```
cd /d "%programdata%\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\System"
```

In earlier operating systems you would have used `%AllUsersProfile%` instead. Variable names are not case-sensitive.

#### Create folders

```
mkdir Settings
```

To save typing you can use `md` instead:

```
md Settings
```

Unlike the `cd` command, `mkdir` and `md` treat spaces as delimiters. Let's say you run this command:

```
md Some settings
```

In this case, two folders are created: `Some` and `settings`. If you intend to create a single folder called `Some settings` you need to use quotes. For consistency, I recommend always using quotes; even when they're not mandatory:

```
md "Settings"
```

You can also specify a full path, like this:

```
md "%programdata%\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\System\Settings"
```

The `System` and `Settings` subfolders don't usually exist, and both would be created in one go.

### Further reading

- [Command-Line Reference](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc754340.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Alwayse quote the paths. paths with space in name must quote.

use this :

```
cd "C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\System"
mkdir Settings
cd "C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu"
dir
move "Default Programs.lnk" "C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\System\Settings"
pause
```

Comment: The actual issue is not related to quotes, in this case. By default, spaces are not treated as delimiters so you might omit quotes when using the `cd` command (although I wouldn't recommend doing so). If you were to run the above commands, you would get the exact same error described by the OP. Why? Because the `Default Programs.lnk` shortcut file is moved to a path that doesn't really exist (the `Start Menu\System` part should be `Start Menu\Programs\System`).

Comment: @and31415 Thank you dear friend :)